# PHP combining variables

Tags: php, string, variables, separator

I have a 'foreach' PHP loop. Each time the loop is run, I am combing the value in the current loop iteration ($CurrentTillID) to a variable.

Here is my code:

```
$separator = ',';
$tillDetails = $tillDetails . $CurrentTillID;
```

I am wanting to add a separator between each $CurrentTillID value.

This is the code that I have tried:

```
$tillDetails = $tillDetails . $CurrentTillID . $separator;
```

This above code does not work. Can I please have some help to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a concatenation operator - `$tillDetails .= $variable`

Comment: You could also use `implode()` to 'stick' some variables together with 'glue'. `implode( "," , array( $tillDetails, $CurrentTillID ) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the separator in between the items you are separating.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to do this:

```
$tillDetails .= $separator . $CurrentTillID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate with .=

```
<?php
$tillDetails = null;
foreach($data as $k=>$v){
    $tillDetails .= $v.',';
}
?>
```

Tho is you only have a single dimension array you may as well forget the foreach and just implode it into a string with your separator:

```
$orig_data = array('till1','till2','till3','yada');
$tillDetails = implode(',',$orig_data);
```